# Can not build the multi-module android app

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, multi-module

I try to make multi module app and get Type com.example.boombadproject.BuildConfig is defined multiple time when I try to run the app , The problem is disappear when I comment the implementation of module

```
    implementation(project(Modules.core))
    /*implementation(project(Modules.onboardingPresentation))
    implementation(project(Modules.onboardingDomain))
    implementation(project(Modules.trackerPresentation))
    implementation(project(Modules.trackerDomain))
    implementation(project(Modules.trackerData))*/
```

I try to clean project, rebluild.I found some solutions to change the pakge name in manifest but still have the issue

--- setting.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        classpath
    }
}
rootProject.name = "BoomBadProject"
include ':app'
include ':onboarding'
include ':onboarding:onboarding_domain'
include ':onboarding:onboarding_presentation'
include ':core'
include ':tracker'
include ':tracker:tracker_data'
include ':tracker:tracker_domain'
include ':tracker:tracker_presentation'
```

-- build.gradle.kts project level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath(Build.androidBuildTools)
            classpath(Build.hiltAndroidGradlePlugin)
            classpath(Build.kotlinGradlePlugin)
            classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1")
            classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0")
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    tasks.register("clean",Delete::class){
        delete(rootProject.buildDir)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your import, are you import these modules in settings.gradle ?

include ':Modules.core'

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response , yes I add it -- 
rootProject.name = "BoomBadProject"
include ':app'
include ':onboarding'
include ':onboarding:onboarding_domain'
include ':onboarding:onboarding_presentation'
include ':core'
include ':tracker'
include ':tracker:tracker_data'
include ':tracker:tracker_domain'
include ':tracker:tracker_presentation'

Comment: I updata the questions and include build.gradle and setting.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifests to ensure that the different modules don't have the same namespace i.e. `com.example.boombadproject` you could change it in two ways:

1. On the manifest file of the module

```
<manifest package="com.example.boombadproject.onboarding"/>
```

2. or Under the android tag on build.gradle file and append the library name etc;

```
android {
   namespace = com.example.boombadproject.onboarding
}
```